# How to handle null value in c#

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I am trying to handle the null value in the directory search

```
     try{
          // some code here
          SearchResult searchResult=directorySearcher.FindOne();
          // some code here
         }
catch(Exception ex)
        {}
```

how to check if the search result is null or not
I tried

```
  if(searchResult==null)
    {
     // value is null
    }
 but still, it goes to catch the exception.
```

Comment: What is the exception, please? At which line do you have the exception?

Comment: Null exception thrown from SearchResult searchResult=directorySearcher.FindOne();

Comment: Please, check if `directorySearcher == null`; another possibility is `searchResult = directorySearcher?.FindOne();` so you'll get `null` (not exception) if `directorySearcher == null`

Comment: I tried it doesn't work

Comment: [Example on ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.searchresult?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) is ... interesting. They also put `myDirectorySearcher.FindOne();` inside a trycatch, despite [FindOne](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.findone?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) should just return null, if nothing is found.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko still I am getting a null exception, I have been working on this for 2 days now